# Asp.net foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is foreach loop check empty index of array or it terminates on that index where elements are ended? for example at index 0 of array the element exists and index 1 is empty and then at index 2 the element exist, is foreach loop check the element at index 2 or terminates at index 1?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing you could check by running the code yourself. I don't know why you need us for that.

Comment: It will be more clear if you add an example

Comment: foreach will successfully loop all elements of an initialized array. If there are 0 elements, it loops 0 times. This is also something you could very easily try yourself. If the array is null, it will break. You can test that, too.

Comment: You're having an XY Problem. I'm guessing something is not being rendered on your web page, and you thought _"I know, `foreach()` must be broken!"_. It's not. Please read [ask] and produce a [mcve] that illustrates your question and reproduces your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let me explain what `foreach` actually does.
It iterates over a collection of elements inside an `IEnumerable`, in order, without skipping anything, even if the current element has the value `null`.

If you have an array with `[5,2,24]`, the elements will be called in oder `5`, `2`, `24` and will stop after that.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @mason Didn't the `without skipping any` imply the answer?

Comment: No. Because it depends on what you mean by skipping when an element at a particular index is empty, or when empty elements are at the end of the array.

Comment: @mason Define _empty elements_. `foreach` will still go over elements that have the value `null`.

Comment: @mason You are probably right with your last part, but I still wanted to try anyways. Updated my answer by adding the information of my last comment..

Answer (score 0):

A foreach loop will run for the length of the array. In you example, there are 3 array elements, but one is empty. The foreach loop will run 3 times in order of the index, 0 then 1 then 2.

Comment: ... and will run in index order.

Comment: correct. I figured that was implied, but then again, I thought foreach also implied length. Point taken

Comment: @mason I never thought of it that way, in a way I am contributing to the problem!

Comment: As I have already gone and answered this one, I will just leave it. In the future I will refrain from answering.

Comment: @mason That is a bit too general. You can also answer a question from pure personal knowledge and experience, that the OP may lack at the specific topic.

Comment: @IanH. This is not one of those questions. This is a question from pure laziness.

Answer (score -2):

Foreach loop runs on the value it contain.
ex: loop contain=[1,2,3,5]
then 
loops based on count of data